# Заполнение пространства в grid-сетке

Tags: html, css, grid

Вот что дано на макете: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот что получилось у меня (пришлось уменьшить размер страницы чтобы всё поместилось в скрин): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот код:

```css
.portfolio__items{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 23px;
}

.portfolio__item-img{
  background: #EDEDED;
  color: #EDEDED;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.portfolio__item-img:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(36, 33, 33, 0.8), rgba(36, 33, 33, 0.8)), #EDEDED;
  border: 12px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.portfolio__item-title{
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.portfolio__item-descr{
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio__items">
      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-1" style="height: 495px; max-height: 495px;">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-2" style="height: 290px; max-height: 290px;">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-3" style="height: 365px; max-height: 365px;">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-4" style="height: 320px; max-height: 320px;">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-5" style="height: 395px; max-height: 395px;">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__item-img_two-elem">
        <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-6" style="height: 290px; max-height: 290px; margin-bottom: 22px;">
          <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT</div>
          <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-7" style="height: 290px; max-height: 290px;">
          <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT</div>
          <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-8" style="height: 525px; max-height: 525px;">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__item-img portfolio__item-img-9" style="height: 570px; max-height: 570px;">
        <div class="portfolio__item-title">OCCA CUPIDATAT</div>
        <div class="portfolio__item-descr">DESIGN</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Необходимо заполнить пространство между первым рядом и вторым рядом, как это сделать - не знаю, прошу знающих помочь

Comment: А высота каждого блока статичная или нет в плане пропорций? Просто если не статичная, то я сомневаюсь что получится. А если статичная, тогда вам нужно разделить "grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr);" на определённое количество строк - я насчитал 9. Потом при помощи "grid-row-start" и "grid-row-end" разложить их в нужных пропорциях. Почему на 9? - Потому-что переходы в 2 блоках неравномерные и получается один блок в трехблоковом столбце будет занимать три строки. А первый столбец будет занимать 5 и 4 строки. Третий столбец наоборот 4 и 5. Пятый 3 и 6.

Comment: Да, высота у каждого статичная, потому и задал инлайново каждому элементу свою высоту

Comment: Вот теперь уберите им style в html разметке - это не нужно. Вы должны сделать как я описал выше. И вытащите 6 и 7 из portfolio__item-img_two-elem

Comment: Вы же столбцы оформили в 4 ряда, точно также вам нужно оформить строки.

Comment: А разве не должно быть так, что строк всего 2? ну там в первом 4, во втором столько же, только в одном уже два элемента внутри

Comment: Я просто сейчас сделал так, высота родительского контейнера увеличилась, а в целом столько места не нужно. Пока максимум задействовал там 4 строки, и то потому что высоты теперь нет (upd: убрал 6 и 7 элементы из обертки, теперь все как надо)

Comment: Вот пример вам сделал, по нему ориентируйтесь.

Comment: Просто если вы устанавливаете определённую высоту элементам, потом пожалеете, когда контент не будет помещаться в отведённую ему высоту. Высота элемента содержащего динамические составляющие всегда должна быть неопределённой - auto или 100%.

Comment: Я думаю вам проще использовать `masonry`. Это явно то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот я вам сделал примерно как это должно делаться, а там уже вы сами додумывайте)).

```css
body {
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
.item {
  background-color: gray;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr;);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr);
  gap: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
.item-1, .item-2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
.item-3, .item-4, .item-5 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
.item-6, .item-7 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
.item-8, .item-9 {
  grid-column-start: 4;
}
.item-1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
.item-2 {
  grid-row-start: 5;
  grid-row-end: 10;
}
.item-3 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}
.item-4 {
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 7;
}
.item-5 {
  grid-row-start: 7;
  grid-row-end: 10;
}
.item-6 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 6;
}
.item-7 {
  grid-row-start: 6;
  grid-row-end: 10;
}
.item-8 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}
.item-9 {
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item-1"></div>
  <div class="item item-2"></div>
  <div class="item item-3"></div>
  <div class="item item-4"></div>
  <div class="item item-5"></div>
  <div class="item item-6"></div>
  <div class="item item-7"></div>
  <div class="item item-8"></div>
  <div class="item item-9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Суть, кажется, уловил) спасибо

Comment: Вот так посмотрите, доделал для вас.

Comment: Нет, ничего не получилось. То места много для элементов, то места мало - какая-то каша получается всё равно по итогу. Например, сказал элементу №1, что он будет занимать высоту в 5 строк, он занял, а элементу 2 места не хватает. Задаю чтоб начинался с 5 строки и шел до 9, но этого мало. И даже если так сделать, почему-то по итогу когда самому последнему элементу задаю, что он должен "отсюда до сюда" быть - резко все элементы перестают "слушаться",  возвращаются к первоначальному виду. Однако спасибо Вам за потраченное время
Upd: высота родителя 100%

Comment: Вы пока путаетесь просто в параметрах, вам нужно привыкнуть.

Comment: Что-ж, я еще немного "поэкспериментировал", так сказать, и все проблемы решены! еще раз спасибо за помощь и за потраченное время)